# C program compiles but no output

Tags: c, header-files

I am trying to learn creating header file in C and including it in my main.c func() . I created a simple tut1.c file with function named call() and a tut1.h header file which externs tut1.c function named call(). Thats it, now i am using eclipse Juno for C/C++ on linux fedora. I dont get any compile error but the code wont output? I tried on console and eclipse in vain. Can you check please? Thanks

```
---main.c-----

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "tut1.h"

int main (void)

{
    int tut1(void);

    return 0;
}

-----tut1.c------

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "tut1.h"

int call (void)
{
    int *ptr;
    int i;

        ptr = &i;
       *ptr = 10;

    printf ("%d we are printing the value of &i\n", &i);
    printf ("%d we are printing the value of *ptr\n", *ptr);
    printf ("%d we are printing the value of ptr\n", ptr);
    printf ("%d we are printing the value of &ptr\n", &ptr);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}

----tut1.h----

#ifndef TUT1_H_
#define TUT1_H_

extern int call (void);

#endif
```

Comment: Why are you declaring a nonexistent function (`tut1()`) within `main()`?

Comment: No output because you are not calling anything - just declaring a function, then returning 0.

Comment: Note that this program also invokes undefined behavior: Pointers and addresses **must** be printed using a `%p` format specifier and the argument **must** be (cast to) a `void *`.

Comment: Hi Jens, I understand %p but what do you mean by "The argument must be case to void* ? " in my above example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not seeing anything because you're not calling the `call()` function from your `main()` function.

The `main()` function is the default entry point when you run the program, i.e. the first function that gets called during execution.

To execute the function `call()` you would need to call this from `main()` as follows :

```
int main (void)

{
    int result = call();

    return 0;
}
```

BTW, this line `int tut1(void);` within your `main()` just declares a function, which you do not seem to have defined anywhere. So I have removed it in the above shown code.

Comment: Thank you all. Yes I realised my mistake. Really appreciate your feedback, each one was valuable. Cheers